# git: remove dead branch after a rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

I have the following git branches: master and dev:

```
   *master*
      |
A--B--C
   \--D--E
         |
       *dev*
```

After rebasing dev on master, I have:

```
   *master*
      |
A--B--C--D'--E'
   \--D--E   |
             |
           *dev*
```

So D and E remain in a 'dead branch'. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to: because commits `D` and `E` have no<sup>1</sup> name pointing to them, they're eligible for "garbage collection".  Eventually git will run a `git gc` and throw them away for you.

If you want to speed this up, you can run `git gc` yourself, but then footnote 1 comes into play. :-)

---

<sup>1</sup>This is not quite true.  While the branch-name `dev` now contains the ID of commit `E'` (the copy), there are two reflog entries, one for `dev` and one for `HEAD`, that allow you (and git) to find commit `E`.  There is also a semi-special name, `ORIG_HEAD`, which lasts until something else replaces its contents (another rebase, or a `git merge`, for instance).

By default, most reflog entries persist for either 30 days or 90 days, depending on whether the commit is reachable from the current branch head.  Once the reflog entry expires, *then* the object is a candidate for garbage collection.

As yet another precaution, `git gc` leaves "loose objects" alone unless they are at least two weeks old (by default—this is configurable, and there is a `--prune=` option to override this as well).  So in general, for a nominally-abandoned object to go away, it:

- must be at least two weeks old;
- must have had any reflog entries expire (generally 30 days); and
- must not have any alternatives names keeping it available.

(And of course, `git gc` must run, although git automatically runs this whenever it "looks promising".)

Comment: Ok, so D and E should disappear if I run gc in a month. I will come back in a month to let you know. In the mean time, I will look if it can happen faster.

Comment: You can *force* it (immediately) by (1) removing any `ORIG_HEAD` and/or reflog entries and (2) running `git gc --prune=now`.  To get reflogs expired "now" (so that the `--prune=now` takes effect) you can run `git reflog --expire=now --expire-unreachable=now` first.  Note that this is telling git to remove all your safety/recovery mechanisms, so you need to be *very* sure about this.  You can instead use `git reflog delete` to delete specific entries (again look on both `HEAD` and the branch reflog) for a more surgical strike.  (Or just do stuff on a clone for safety.)

Comment: Tagged commits of dead branch will not be deleted. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33284908/13320138

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will break if you have extra commits around, they're just there in case you want to move around your reflog or otherwise refer to them later.

However, if you want to forcibly remove extra commits and other unnecessary objects, you can use [`git gc`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc). If you want it to remove as many extra commits/objects as possible (and you don't care as much about speed), you can use `git gc --aggressive`.

**Note:** Technically, D and E aren't in a branch anymore. Branches are simply pointers to commits, they don't have a history of their own (besides the history of the specific commits they point to). As a result, when you rebased dev, git left the D and E commits around in case you want to access them later, even though they're no longer on a branch.

Comment: Actually, `--aggressive` simply turns on `git repack`'s `-f` option and sets the `--depth` and `--window` values (to 250 and 250, or whatever you configure for `gc.aggressivedepth` and `gc.aggressivewindow`).

Comment: @torek - in my experience `git gc --aggressive` did more than just that.  i can't say what specifically since it would 100% of the time crash my machine by exhausting memory, while `git repack` would always work.

Comment: @AndrewC: interesting, I got the above from looking at current (git 2.2) source, perhaps at some point it did something else too.

Comment: @torek mine was based on usage only from whatever version was branch tip over July 2014. I'll retest with current version.